# django-admin.py startproject Inventory . is not working?

Tags: python, django, windows-xp

I am facing an error after installing Django, I tried (venv) C:\Users\Pallavai\DJANGO PROJECTS\Inventory>django-admin.py startproject inventory . Whenever I try this command, suddenly my sublime editor will open with code as given below. Any idea what is wrong?

```
#!c:\users\pallavai\django~1\invent~1\venv\scripts\python.exe
from django.core import management

if __name__ == "__main__":
    management.execute_from_command_line()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you're showing seems to be the code of the django-admin.py file. You're forgetting to execute python in your command.

It should be:

```
django-admin.exe startproject inventory .
```

Comment: Sir, it works. But why it is admin.exe rather than admin.py?

Comment: .py is the file, .exe is the executable. The .py file includes the code, and the .exe runs the program. If the answer is correct, please mark it as so by clicking the green tick symbol.